# Asterisk Warning-Sound not beeing played to callee

Tags: asterisk, bridge

I am connecting two channels with the Bridge Application Bridge(Local/XXXXXXXX@sipname, FL(180000,120000)x). The warning sound should be played 120 seconds before the call ends. In the past this worked perfectly but now suddenly the sound is not beeing played to the callee. I checked everything but can't find the reason for it.

In the CLI it shows everything correctly but still it is not beeing played to the callee.

```
> Limit Data for this call:
   > timelimit      = 180000 ms (180.000 s)
   > play_warning   = 120000 ms (120.000 s)
   > play_to_caller = yes
   > play_to_callee = yes
   > warning_freq   = 0 ms (0.000 s)
   > start_sound    = enter
   > warning_sound  = gong
   > end_sound      =
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a /n to the Context in the Dial-Cmd that fixed it for me.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-local-channels/